# Mass rename of classes solving references in Smalltalk with the Refactoring Browser

Tags: refactoring, smalltalk, pharo, automated-refactoring

I want to rename all classes starting with the prefix SMP to RS, including references in source code (direct ones like SMPClass1 and indirect ones like Smalltalk at: #SMPClass2) and in class and method comments. Can the current RBParseTreeRewriter do this?
An equivalent without the parse tree rewriter would be:

```
Smalltalk allClassesDo: [ :class |
(class name beginsWith: 'SW2')
    ifTrue: [ class rename: 'PR' , (class name allButFirst: 3) ] ].
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this can be done, but not with the `RBParseTreeRewriter` (this is a low-level tool to rewrite source-code internally used by refactorings).

From OmniBrowser select in the context menu *Refactor > Class Regex*. Then modify and accept the template as follows:

```
ORClassRegexRefactoring new
  renameClasses;
  replace: '^SW2(.*)$' with: 'PR$1' ignoreCase: false;
  yourself
```

This will automatically rename all classes and references.

Comment: Thanks, any specific reason to require OmniBrowser? Could be the environment be specified by code to limit changes to a specific package?

Comment: OmniBrowser is not a requirement, but of course it makes it significantly simpler. All refactorings can be triggered from workspace scripts.

Comment: To scope the refactoring to a specific package select an entity of the package in OmniBrowser and click on 'Refactoring scope > Package'. In the resulting browser perform the rename refactoring described above. Again, this can also be done from a workspace script, but then you are on your own :-)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to rename the classes in a single package to make the following code:

```
(SystemOrganizer default classesInCategory: 'my pakage name') do: [ :class |
    "Adding the prefix PRE classes"
    (class name beginsWith: 'PRE') ifFalse: [ class rename: 'PRE' , class name ] 
]
```